# Trying to understand how scipy.optimize can be used?

Tags: python

I am trying to use stats.optimize.minimize function. First, I am trying something very simple.

I define:

```
lik1 = lambda n,k,p: math.log(stats.binom.pmf(k,n,p))
```

I am trying to see if minimize will give me the correct MLE, which is, `k/n == p`.

Then I try:

```
optimize.minimize(lik1, 0.5, args=(10,2))
```

where I am assuming `n == 10` and `k == 2` and my guess for `p` (the argument x0) is `0.5`. I get the following error:

```
      fun: nan
 hess_inv: array([[1]])
      jac: array([ nan])
  message: 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'
     nfev: 3
      nit: 0
     njev: 1
   status: 2
  success: False
        x: array([ 0.5])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A few changes:

1. Select a more appropriate minimization method for this problem.  The minimize function defaults to the BFGS method when no constraints or bounds are provided which is a method for unconstrained optimization.  It fails because it tries to evaluate the function for values of p > 1.  You could provide some reasonable bounds, or I've found here that using the TNC method works in this instance.
2. The order of the function arguments should be (p, n, k)
3. You want to maximize the log, or equivalently minimize the negative of the log.

Code:

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.stats
import scipy.optimize

lik1 = lambda p, n, k: -sp.log(sp.stats.binom.pmf(k, n, p))
res = sp.optimize.minimize(lik1, 0.5, args=(10, 2), method='TNC')
print(res)
```

Output:

```
     fun: array([ 1.19736175])
     jac: array([  1.22124533e-05])
 message: 'Converged (|f_n-f_(n-1)| ~= 0)'
    nfev: 10
     nit: 4
  status: 1
 success: True
       x: array([ 0.20000019])
```

Comment: I am trying to understand, how to choose between different methods? scipy.optimize documentation, lists the different methods that can be used, but does not mention more details about the methods. For example, in L-BFGS-B, what do L and B stand for?

Comment: scipy assumes some level of familiarity with the methods and theory so that you can choose an appropriate method for your problem.  There is no single best method for every problem and the various methods are all good to certain types of problems.  There are many online resources if you search for the method names.  For L-BFGS-B, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS#L-BFGS-B